# Please help to identify these coins

Tags: identification, currency, numismatics

First coin: it dates 1670. The coat of arms seems to show the checkerboard as in [Flag of Bavaria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Bavaria), but that's speculation

[image: First coin, side 01]
[image: First coin, side 02]

---

Second coin: it dates 1770. The inscription beginns with **D.G.MAX.IOS.** etc., which could mean *Maximillian Iosephus from Gods grace*, <strike>however, this is again speculation</strike>.

**Update:** This coins most probably shows [Maximillian III Joseph, Elector of Bavaria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximilian_III_Joseph,_Elector_of_Bavaria). However, I still don't know which coin it is.

[image: Second coin, side 01]
[image: Second coin, side 02]

---

**Some context:** these coins were found in a small box with mostly coins from the 1890's from mainly the Austria-Hungarian Empire and successor states, and the German empire and successor states. The two coins depicted above, stand out from the others as these are considerably older.
As most of the coins stem from central Europe, and the find was made in Austria, I strongy suspect, that these coins might as well be from central Europe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First one is [German States MANSFELD-EISLEBEN 1/3 Thaler](https://www.ngccoin.com/price-guide/world/german-states-mansfeld-eisleben-1-3-thaler-km-67-1668-1673-cuid-1146171-duid-1383339)
[image]

(search for: coin george dragon 1670)

see also [Thaler in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thaler)

---

Second one seems to be [10 Kreuzer - Maximilian III Joseph](https://en.numista.com/catalogue/pieces19272.html)

[image]

also discussed [here](http://ccoins.ru/pages/bavaria_en.html)

(searched for: coin 1770 ell)

see also [Kreuzer in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kreuzer)

Comment: The second one's in fact a 10 Kreuzer coin - see http://coinquest.com/cgi-bin/cq/coins?main_coin=16996